# ec2-describe-instances does not return a response

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

I am working with an application that uses EC2 CLI.

I have a running instance in us-east-1 region.

When I run

```
ec2-describe-instances --region us-east-1
```

it does not return anything.

However,

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1
```

returns the expected json response.

`ec2-describe-volume` does not work either.

I have set up EC2_HOME and EC2_URL as described in the documentation.

```
export EC2_HOME="/usr/local/ec2/ec2-api-tools-1.7.3.0"
export EC2_URL=https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

`ec2-describe-regions` works as expected.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that CLI tools were already installed via package manager before I installed it from source. Removing ec2-api-tools package fixed the problem.